# R: how to remove this tiny axis margin in plot

Tags: r, plot, margin, plotrix

I want to get rid the small margin close to zero on X and Y value (red line on pic), and plot ONLY what is showed in red square.

I tried setting `par(mar = rep(0, 4)` and `xlim=c(0, ...)`, `ylim=c(0, ...)` but R still keeps adding this tiny margin. How to get rid of it?

[image: plot in R with margins]

EDIT: 
another point of view on my problem: 
after running:

```
require(plotrix)
axisRange <- c(0,500)
plot(NULL, xlim = axisRange, ylim=axisRange)
draw.circle(0, 0, 200, col = "white", border = "red")
```

I end up with a circle positioned not in "true" 0,0 point: 
[image: Circle should be on 0,0 point]

EDIT2: 
Actually what I want to do, is to plot circles of different radius, and save it as an image. That is why I care about the margins.
I end up with something like this (spots on the corners are for the reference):

[image]

And should be more like this: 
[image]

Comment: no, I want to plot circle of given radius and get rid of the margin

Comment: please see edit. Yes, my mistake - I use plotrix to draw circle. But maybe there is something better than that to recreate my image of circles?

Comment: Are you looking for `xaxs`  and `yaxs`?  Using your plotrix example:  Set `par(mar = rep(0, 4))`, `plot(NULL, xlim=axisRange, ylim=axisRange, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")`. Then, add the circle.

Comment: @Jota Almost! but it works (like I want) only on the Y axis (from the left side). It is still leaving the margin on top, bottom and right

Comment: ..actually I just saw it depends on window scaling on RStudio... :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `xaxs` and `yaxs` arguments to "i" as opposed to the default of "r".  From the `par` help page:

> Style "r" (regular) first extends the data range by 4 percent at each
>   end and then finds an axis with pretty labels that fits within the
>   extended range.
>
> Style "i" (internal) just finds an axis with pretty labels that fits
>   within the original data range.

```
library(plotrix)
axisRange <- c(0,500)
par(mar = rep(0,4))
plot(NULL, xlim = axisRange, ylim=axisRange, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
draw.circle(0, 0, 200, col = "white", border = "red")
```

Gives:

[image]